# How to get an image to line up with text tag?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create this in bootstrap 3:

[image]

However, right now I have got this:

[image]

My image is not lined up perfectly with the `h4` tag and my `p` tags will not stay in a line as the first image. I am using bootstrap 3, so I am getting used it everything, and I was wondering if anyone can help me achieve this look. So far I have:

```css
.col-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.col-content p {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}

.col-icon {
  font-size: 48px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-content">
      <h4>Web <span class="highlight">Development</span></h4>
      <p>Praesent sodales, quam vitae gravida interdum, ex mi bibendum enim, sit amet tristique mi quam vel odio. Donec non nunc condimentum, hendrerit elit sed, condimentum magna. Suspendisse imperdiet purus vel ornare cursus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-content">
      <h4>Internet <span class="highlight">Marketing</span></h4>
      <p>Curabitur et diam elementum, mollis tortor a, malesuada turpis. Vivamus gravida, justo et molestie sollicitudin, erat lorem tempus eros, vel laoreet nibh urna ac nunc, vestibulum neque vitae pellentesque efficitur.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-content">
      <h4>Client <span class="highlight">Support</span></h4>
      <p>Sed porta erat vel ipsum maximus, eget maximus est maximus. Maecenas at venenatis nibh, sit amet suscipit odio. In feugiat vehicula dui. In felis enim, maximus a dolor semper efficitur elit euismod magna quis commodo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am just trying to make it look like the first image with bootstrap 3.

Comment: your icon has a padding-top that might be the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `text-align: center` from `.col-content p` to avoid the text-centering in the paragraphs and change `padding: 20px 10px;` to `padding: 0 10px 20px 10px;` in `.col-icon` to move the icons up to the top of their container:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wpaebo

Answer (score 1):

for line up use `display:inline-flex;align-item: flex-start;` and remove `text-align: center;` from `p` tag

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `top` and `left` while making the icon `position:relative`

```
position: relative;
top: -11px;
left: 8px;
```

```css
.col-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.col-content p {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}

.col-icon {
  font-size: 48px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  top: -11px;
  left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-content">
      <h4>Web <span class="highlight">Development</span></h4>
      <p>Praesent sodales, quam vitae gravida interdum, ex mi bibendum enim, sit amet tristique mi quam vel odio. Donec non nunc condimentum, hendrerit elit sed, condimentum magna. Suspendisse imperdiet purus vel ornare cursus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-content">
      <h4>Internet <span class="highlight">Marketing</span></h4>
      <p>Curabitur et diam elementum, mollis tortor a, malesuada turpis. Vivamus gravida, justo et molestie sollicitudin, erat lorem tempus eros, vel laoreet nibh urna ac nunc, vestibulum neque vitae pellentesque efficitur.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-content">
      <h4>Client <span class="highlight">Support</span></h4>
      <p>Sed porta erat vel ipsum maximus, eget maximus est maximus. Maecenas at venenatis nibh, sit amet suscipit odio. In feugiat vehicula dui. In felis enim, maximus a dolor semper efficitur elit euismod magna quis commodo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```